# Image field: make source image private, but thumbnails public?

Tags: 8, users, media, files

Is it possible to set uploaded images to be stored in the private folder, so that the source files are protected (only accessible for authenticated users) but to make the derived images (generated through the image styles, e.g. thumbnails etc) publicly visible for anonymous users?

My idea would be to have a gallery where the medium-size version of the images are visible to anonymous visitors, but only registered users would have access to the full-size images (source file).